# In VSE, is it possible to have keyframes adapt to clip length? (relative position)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transforms, keyframes, movie-clip-editor

I have added transform keyframes to the beginning and the end of a movie clip. When I decide to change the length of the clip, the keyframes keep their position. Is there any way they would keep position relative to the clip? So if let's say it is located at the end, when I shorten or stretch the clip, it is still at the end of the it? Basically what I want is a relative keyframe position. I haven't been successful in finding a solution.

Comment: Nope sorry. I don't think that you can apply a driver to a keyframe position.

Comment: is it possible to snap the keyframe?

Comment: You can snap individual key frames but not a group in a relative way. They all jump to the same location. You can offset them by using G key and typing the frame offset e.g. G (key) +(key) 30 will move the selected keyframes 30 frames to the right.

Comment: and how would i snap one key frame? i tried with ctrl and other but didnt work

Comment: Select keyframe, then move playhead to new location, then press the Shift-S key, select Snap type "Current frame"

Comment: Awesome! It works. It's not perfect as the driver would be, but it's just one step further. Way more efficient than manual move. Thank you. You should make that an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Park the play head at the end of the strip. Open the dope sheet view and select the last keyframe, then press the Shift-S key, select Snap type "Current frame".

To move all keyframes by the same amount, select all keyframes then press G key and type the offset value in frames and press enter.